# Error at 15:19 no viable alternative at character ';' In Pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have the following code in pine which looks like this:

```
strategy("My script", overlay = true)

input high = close;
input low = close;
input period = 20;
input standardDeviation = 2;
```

This is producing the following error:

```
Error at 15:19 no viable alternative at character ';'
```

Could you please advise how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use line terminator `';'` there, instead leave it as none(blank).

```
//@version=5

strategy("My script", overlay = true)

varhigh = input(close,"source for high:")
varlow = input(close,"source for low:")
period = input.int(20,"period")
standardDeviation = input.int(2, "Standard Deviation")
```